# Obtain bounding box of <use> with external reference

Tags: dom, d3.js, svg

I am writing an application that uses D3 to make some SVG charts. This application renders a number of annotations onto the charts.

The annotations appear as icons, so I have made an external XML file containing the icons defined within a `<defs>`  section, and reference them by inserting a `<use>` element something like this:

```
<use x="100" y="50" xlink:href="defs.xml#iconname" />
```

I want to lay out the icons so that they are not overlapping and obscuring each other. In order to find out if they are overlapping, I attempt to obtain their bounding boxes.

My problem is that when I try to obtain the bounding boxes, using either `getBBox()` or `getBoundingClientRect()`, the returned rectangles have zero width and zero height.

The following sample illustrates the problem:

a.html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

            <use id="used_icon" x="100" y="100" xlink:href="b.xml#test_icon" />

        </svg>

        <script>

            var u = document.getElementById("used_icon");

            var rect = u.getBoundingClientRect();
            console.log("getBoundingClientRect = %d,%d - %d,%d", rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);

            var box = u.getBBox();
            console.log("getBBox = x=%d,y=%d - w=%d,h=%d", box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height);


        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

b.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <defs>
        <g id="test_icon">
            <rect width="50" height="50" />
        </g>
    </defs>

</svg>
```

The output of this, in both Firefox is:

```
getBoundingClientRect = 8,8 - 8,8
getBBox = x=0,y=0 - w=0,h=0
```

and Chrome:

```
getBoundingClientRect = 107,107 - 107,107
getBBox = x=0,y=0 - w=0,h=0
```

If I place the `<defs>` inline in the same document, this does not occur and I get correct width and height (although incorrect x & y in Chrome due to [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=512081)). But I would prefer not to have them in the same document, so that I can centralize the definition of all my icons.

I assume the reason for this is the asynchronous nature of referencing externally definitions - the browser may have to fetch them. Note that the page is constructed dynamically so it is not just a case of waiting until `onLoad` or similar event is emitted.

Is there any way I can get a callback when the external references have been loaded?